# Does non-commuting $\mathfrak{g}$ imply non-abelian $G$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Question 8.1 in Kristopher Tapp's introductory text on matrix groups asks to show that $SO(n)$ is non-abelian ($n>2$) by finding two elements of $so(n)$ that do not commute.

Why is this method valid?

At least in the text, he only proves that $[A,B]=0$ implies $e^A e^B = e^{A+B} = e^B e^A$, but does not mention whether the converse is true. The latter being true is the only way I could rationalize his statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely this method is valid for the simple reason that an abelian group is defined to be a group whose elements commute.  If you can identify two elements which do not commute, then the group cannot be abelian.

Comment: @NickR But the point would be to do the "identify two elements which do not commute" bit. We only have elements of the Lie *algebra* which do not commute, not the Lie *group*.

Comment: @Sharkos Thanks.  I see what you mean. It was a rather naive comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is an abelian matrix group.  We show that $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian; that is, $[X, Y] = 0$, for all $X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$.

For any $g \in G$, define $\mathrm{C}_g \colon G \to G$ by $h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$.  Then, $\mathrm{Ad}_g\, \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is defined as $\mathrm{D} \left( \mathrm{C}_g \right)_\mathrm{I}$.  Since $G$ is abelian, $\mathrm{C}_g$ is the identity map, and hence $\mathrm{Ad}_g = \mathrm{Id}$.  Now, $\mathrm{exp}(tX)$ is a path in $G$ beginning at $\mathrm{I}$ with initial velocity $X$.  Therefore, by definition, 
\begin{equation}
[X, Y] = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \bigg|_{t=0} \mathrm{Ad}_{\mathrm{exp} \left( tX \right)} Y = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \bigg|_{t=0} Y = 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: This solution was synthesized from the two solutions of Sharkos and Alex Youcis.

Comment: That that is «by definition» depends, really, on how the bracket was defined! I always define it as a commutator and then prove the equality you used.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just going off of Tapp's definitions, since those are the only ones I've worked from! :)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $G$ is abelian. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is trivially abelian (you can express $[A,B]$ for elements of the Lie algebra in terms of commutators of elements of the group). Therefore the contrapositive holds: $\mathfrak{g}$ not abelian implies $G$ is not abelian.

---

As I say in the comments, I meant it was *conceptually trivial* that the local $\mathfrak{g}$ inherits the global abelian property.

Since people obviously thought this was worth spelling out, here is the way I have seen this done, taking the definition to be matrix commutators from a matrix Lie group:
$$
g(t) = \exp(Xt),\;h(t) = \exp(Yt) \\
\text{Abelian}\implies \boxed{I = g h g^{-1} h^{-1} = I + [X,Y]t^2 + O(t^3)}
$$
and hence $[X,Y]=0$.

Comment: Thanks Sharkos, can you explain how $[A,B]$ can be written in terms of commutators of elements of the lie group? I cannot think of such a formula.

Comment: This is just hiding everything under the *trivially* word or in the «you can express» which you did not explain at all!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well, I think of it as *conceptually trivial* in the sense that 'the local structure of an abelian group is trivially abelian'. I indicated how to obtain this rigorously in brackets if the OP needed a hint. (The OP did manage to produce a detailed solution, albeit with the help of another answer.) I do not consider this a full detailed answer, but a hint which points out the natural way to go about it.

Comment: @DanDouglas I've illustrated it in the most mechanical way I know; hope this is also of some use in complementing your slightly more general approach. :) (Feel free to accept your own answer of course!)

Comment: Thank you, Sharkos. This is a really important piece of intuition, indeed! :)

Answer (score 3):

The Lie algebra structure on $\def\lie#1{\mathfrak{#1}}\lie{g}$ is defined by the following two-step procedure:

- For a Lie group $G$, each element $g \in G$ acts by conjugation on $G$, $\def\on{\operatorname}\on{Ad}_g \colon h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$.  This map $G \to G$ has a differential map on the tangent space at the identity, $d\on{Ad}_g \colon TG_1 \to TG_1$.  By definition, $\lie{g} = TG_1$ and typically $d\on{Ad}_g$ is also written $\on{Ad}_g$, called the *adjoint action* of $g$ on $\lie{g}$.
- The adjoint action is a Lie group action of $G$ on $\lie{g}$; mainly, the aggregate map $\on{Ad} \colon G \times \lie{g} \to \lie{g}$ is smooth.  It, too, has a differential $d\on{Ad} \colon T(G \times \lie{g})_{(1,0)} \to T\lie{g}_0$.  By general principles of differential topology, we have
  $$T(G \times \lie{g})_{(1,0)}
   \cong TG_1 \times T\lie{g}_0
   \cong \lie{g} \times \lie{g}$$
  where we have used the fact that $\lie{g}$ is a vector space and thus isomorphic to its own tangent space at any point.  Thus, $d\on{Ad}$ is some kind of bivariate map from $\lie{g}$ to itself; in fact, it's the Lie bracket.

It follows from the above definition that if $\on{Ad}_g \colon G \to G$ is the constant function $1$ for all $g \in G$, then ultimately, the Lie bracket is zero.  The former is the case whenever $G$ is abelian.  Taking the contrapositive, if $\lie{g}$ is nonabelian, then $G$ is necessarily as well.

Comment: If $\operatorname{Ad}_g$ is the identity then the Lie bracket is _zero_.

Comment: What a dumb typo.

Answer (score 2):

If $A,B$ do not commute then $e^Ae^B = e^{A+B+ \frac{1}{2}[A,B]+ \cdots }$ and the higher terms are nested commutators. This is the Baker Campbell Hausdorff relation. Since elements of the Lie group close to the identity can be written as exponentials of the algebra this shows the noncommutativity. Intuitively, the higher order terms are much smaller for elements near the identity. This is just a sketch. There is probably a clever argument which avoids the BCH identity.

Comment: It's not hard to prove without the BCH formula that any fixed $X, Y\in \mathfrak{g}$ have $\exp tX\exp tY = \exp Z$ for $Z = tX + tY + \frac{1}{2} t^2 [X, Y] + O(t^3)$ as $t\to\infty$. (I seem to recall that this is an exercise in Helgason's intro book on Lie groups, for example). That's enough to prove the result in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You need connectivity.

Pick any element $g\in G$ and any element $X\in\mathfrak{g}$. Consider that since $\exp(tX)\in G$, we have by the abelianess of $G$ that $g\exp(tX)g^{-1}=\exp(tX)$. So, if we differentiate we get, fortuitously, $\text{Ad}(g)X=X$.

Now, take $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathfrak{g}$. Apply the above argument with $g=\exp(tX)$ to see that $\text{Ad}(\exp(tX))Y=Y$. Differentiate to get the desired result.

Comment: You should have written $\mathrm{Ad}(g) X = X$, and it appears your assumption of connectedness is superfluous; see my answer that was inspired by yours and Sharkos'.

Comment: @DanDouglas I fixed the error. and connectedness is needed, in fact.

Comment: Indeed, there are non-abelian Lie groups with abelia Lie algebra.

Comment: I just posted the aforementioned solution.  Would you mind checking it out?  I don't believe I needed that $G$ was path-connected.  Also, note that you cannot assume $\mathrm{exp} \colon \mathfrak{g} \to G$ is surjective unless $G$ is both path-connected and compact.

Comment: For example, $\mathrm{exp} \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$ is not surjective.

Comment: @DanDouglas, you *do* need connectedness: just take a non-abelian finite group $H$ and consider the Lie group $\mathbb R\times G$.

Comment: Connectedness seems to be relevant only if you want to prove the inverse statement that abelian $\mathfrak{g}$ implies abelian $G$, not the question that Dan asked.

Comment: @Mariano: You just have the small typo of writing $G$ instead of $H$; otherwise, as Ryan notes, you have shown that non-abelian $G$ can have abelian $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: It is obvious the the Lie algebra, and whether it is Abelian, only depends on the connected component of the Lie group containing the identity. However a disconnected Abelian Lie group will have an Abelian connected component containing the identity and therefore an Abelian Lie algebra; no connectedness assumption needed here.